# mongodb not returning the integer, mappingexception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

Im trying to return an integer using mongo repository, the value i want to get is the id, below is the mongo query being used to extract the id field from the database as an integer

```
package com.example.messagestomongodb.repository;

import com.example.messagestomongodb.domain.CovidCases;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CasesRepository extends MongoRepository<CovidCases, Integer> {

@Query(value = "{ '_id' : ?0 }", fields = "{ '_id' : 1}")
Integer returnIntegerFromDB(Integer id);


}
```

i am trying to check for duplicate records which contain the id when it already exists in the database, the reason for this is so i can DLQ the message as i am working with RabbitMQ

```
public boolean checkForDuplicateRecords(Integer id, CovidCases cases){
    Integer existingId = casesRepository.returnIntegerFromDB(id);

    if (cases.getId().equals(existingId)){
        log.info("existingid is {} and casesid is {}",existingId,cases.getId());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am getting the following error when i run the application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Expected to read Document Document{{_id=1}} into type class java.lang.Integer but didn't find a PersistentEntity for the latter!
```

There seems to be an error getting the data from mongo but i am returning an integer and _id is set to an integer data type in mongo aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query with just `value` and `fields` in a JPA `@Query`, it would still return instances of your entity.
Therefore, the return type of your method should be `CovidCases`. You can later, count number of documents to get the required result.

```
@Query(value = "{ '_id' : ?0 }", fields = "{ '_id' : 1}")
CovidCases returnIntegerFromDB(Integer id);
```

To get count directly using `@Query`, add the flag `count` to it:

```
@Query(value = "{ '_id' : ?0 }", fields = "{ '_id' : 1}", count = true)
Long returnIntegerFromDB(Integer id);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, it has fixed the error. however is there a way to return the actual id as opposed to just a count which is 0 or 1?

Comment: You have the `id` as you queried with it! You can check count is 0 or 1 or whether the entity is `null` or not for the first query. Not sure if there's any other way to do this.